# Opening PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA terminal starts a new Xorg session

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, zsh, xorg

I have installed PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.1 and Arch Linux with Zsh as my default shell and i3 is my window manager.

When I open a new terminal window inside PyCharm, it starts a new Xorg session (`exec i3` I think) and switches to a new TTY. When I come back to my main session with `ctrl+alt+F1` I see these logs in the terminal:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.12.5-1-ARCH x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux lenovo-laptop 4.12.8-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 14:08:02 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=8efaeb16-67b6-4063-a130-7e1a10cb0d2f rw quiet
Build Date: 13 August 2017  09:37:50PM

Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Sep  7 09:00:01 2017
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Name Lost. Is Another notification daemon running?
[libi3] ../../i3-4.13/libi3/font.c Using Pango font monospace, size 8
[libi3] ../../i3-4.13/libi3/font.c X11 root window dictates 96.094581 DPI
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: auto-detected "i3bar"
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
```

When I set the shell to bash in settings it works normally.
How do I make terminal behave as normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal and uncheck the "Shell integration" checkbox and click OK. Terminal should behave as normal.

This is happening because when "Shell integration" is checked PyCharm (and IntelliJ IDEA) sources a .zshrc file located in the terminal folder under plugins of PyCharm distribution.

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal.html :

> Shell integration:
>
> If this option is selected, the terminal first loads
> a custom rc config file (located in the terminal folder under plugins
> of PyCharm distribution) which provides an additional set-up, and then
> the user's rc file. Note that presently shell integration works for
> Bash/sh (bashrc), zsh(zshrc) and fish shell (config.fish).

An alternative solution is to comment  out this code in `/opt/pycharm-professional/plugins/terminal/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -n $LOGIN_SHELL ]; then
  if [ -f "$DOTDIR/.zlogin" ]; then
       source "$DOTDIR/.zlogin"
  fi
fi
```